# Apache log file: show IPs that access us 24/7

Tags: apache, awk

In my quest to catch robots, I would like to find a way to extract IP addresses from our Apache access logs which have requests in every hour of a 24 hour period.

For example this will show me a list and a count of requests per IPs that requested /bla/

```
find . -name logfile.*00 -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep -h '"GET /bla/' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Would there be some kind of awk that would tell me which IPs are present in all hours of the day?

Alternatively some free weblog analyser that could do the same.

Some information about the situation:

1. Our robot.txt is blocking all non-static files but is ignored by the majority of our abusers
2. At the moment I am only interested in some tool or awk statement that can give me a list of IPs that access us 24/7 since a normal user will access us 6-9 hours per day but from different timezones.
3. we already have several methods to detect and blacklist IPs and ranges of IPs but I want to see how the spread are on robots that are just turned on and runs non-stop.

The awk statement above is providing

```
Req  IP
3234 111.222.333.444
 234 222.222.333.444
5234 333.222.333.444
```

and I am looking for

```
IP              Hrs
111.222.333.444 24
222.222.333.444 24
333.222.333.444 24
```

or better:

```
IP              Hrs Req
111.222.333.444 24  3234
222.222.333.444 24   234
333.222.333.444 24  5234
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep recommending Piwik found at http://piwik.org/. It is one of the best log file analysis tools out there and it is free! This is an ***excellent*** tool!!

You will find that is it not access over 24 hours. Google and Bing fall into these categories. You will want to be looking for a few things:

- Did they access an image?
- Did they access robots.txt?
- Are they accessing your site at a reasonable speed? Is it human or machine?
- Are they accessing a normal/reasonable amount of pages? Is it human or machine?

There are more factors, but this is enough. You will be able to quickly determine human from machine very quickly with just these factors.

What you do not want to do is make too many assumptions. For example, throw out the concept of using any agent name as some kind of indication. It is junk data.

What you need to do is research domain names and IP addresses and begin to know who these people (lack of a better term) are. Of course there are the obvious such as Google, Bing, Yandex, and Baidu. Some will be legitimate SEO sites such as MOZ, Ahrefs, or Open Site Explorer. You may want to allow accesses for these. However, there are lot of SEO scraper sites and content scraper sites. You will find some accesses from China, Russia, even Poland. These are often junk. You may even see competitors using Screaming Frog to discover how your site competes with keyword usage. And of course, let us not forget the script-kiddies that are trying to landscape and hack your site. It will take time of course to get a feel for who is good for our site. However, the discovery of abusers will never end.

You will want to block bad accesses as far away from your web server as possible. This means using a hardware firewall. But if that is not an option for you, you will want to explore the various software firewall options and possibly use ModSecurity and other tools to protect your site. Of course there is always the .htaccess file (assuming Apache).

This is a common practice that webmasters have to perform daily. It is just the reality of things. If you are not sure of an IP address or domain name or even an access pattern, just post it here and I will evaluate it for you and try and help. I study these things as a smaller subject area of my research. I do not always have answers, but most of the time I have one at hand ready to go and of course I can always do some research.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips. I am aware of the above. The reasonable speed is not a point since automated access is against the fair use charter so ANY automated access can and will be blocked when detected. I am looking for the ones that may be adhering to the speed but not to the behaviour expected of humans. I have whois tools and CIDR calculators in my arsenal so I know where they are from when I detect them. That is alas almost never interesting since their ISPs are not cooperating

Comment: PS: Piwik is not an option at all. We have many tools that can do what it does and the abusers only access our dynamically generated html in which I neither can nor will embed any code. I personally use ANALOG and I can use SPLUNK but I would rather just have an awk.

Comment: I use Sawmill personally but will likely add Piwik to my arsenal. Okay, here is another trick but you have to be patient for this one. Evaluate accesses over a period of time such as 3-4 days, a week, a month, or even 6 months. Certain domain names and IP addresses will begin to bubble to the top of the list because they try and fly under the radar as you said by behaving themselves. I keep various scores such as access per x amount of time. This helps to determine the stealth bots.

Comment: Yes, but with 200K addresses per week that is a lot to keep a track of

Comment: Just keep track of the ones that bubble up to the surface first. Once you knock those out, other lessor offenders will show themselves and so on. Trust me. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve it brute force - there are simply too many IPs to handle. 
Just ran this in 24 steps and extracted the IPs that were in all files. 
Added bonus I got to see how many requests they managed to do a day.

```
find . -name access_log.*00 -mtime -2 -print0 | xargs -0 zfgrep --no-filename -w "[13" | grep "2014:00" | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c > $HOME/unique13_00.txt;
find . -name access_log.*00 -mtime -2 -print0 | xargs -0 zfgrep --no-filename -w "[13" | grep "2014:01" | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c > $HOME/unique13_01.txt;
find . -name access_log.*00 -mtime -2 -print0 | xargs -0 zfgrep --no-filename -w "[13" | grep "2014:02" | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c > $HOME/unique13_02.txt;
.
.
```